# Cannot seem to lock GPS, what else can I try?

Tags: gps

With the other answers outdated, I'm asking again: what can I do to make my GPS work? It worked before, but for some reason it just ceased to lock. I haven't done anything to the phone to make it not work.

Phone: LG G3 vs985 - CyanogenMod 12.1 8/27 nightly build - stock kernel - 8/24 GAPPS

GPS is set to high accuracy. WiFi is on. The phone has been restarted, wiped, restored, yelled at, and it still cannot lock.

FasterGPS has the configuration set to NA/US. I had reset it originally, and recalibrated my phone with the GPS Status app. No GPS lock was had.

The phone is literally outside of the building with clear skies.The case and the back is removed, and it still cannot lock GPS.

[image: GPS Status waiting for location]

[image: Guestimation!]

[image: Pretty sure I have this setting right]

Comment: Have you tried other apps already? Is GPS really enabled? `SAT 0/20` is somewhat optimistic, you won't get more than 14 unless you move to space.

Comment: well, `SAT 0/20` says it doesn't even see a single satellite, so it has nothing to fix on. Maybe the GPS unit (or its antenna) gave up.

Comment: @ott-- what other app should I try? It can lock a location after a lot of walking outside and switching between GPS enabled apps. So I know it's there, on, and works after some time.

Comment: @Izzy Is there a way to force it to seek GPS coordinates? Why does it take so long to acquire the satellites now? I have tried this in different parts of the city, in open spaces, on top of buildings, etc.

Comment: @Zlatty I can't tell why, and you can't force it to fix if it doesn't see a single satellite. With all what you have tried (and I assume it worked before with the same ROM – otherwise trying a different ROM might be worth), it might well be a hardware issue.

Comment: Thanks @Izzy. I have tried looking at ifix and other places to see if there is a dedicated GPS antenna, but it does not seem the case. Many moons ago I had opened up the phone to put some thermal paste on the CPU as the phone was overheating, so I thought I nicked something and made the GPS go wonky.

Comment: That sounds like a logical cause – especially if the issue started right after that.

Comment: That's the thing @Izzy, this issue did not appear right after I opened up the phone. I think it has something to do with the gapps and cm12.1 update recently applied. Maybe something with the kernel that I'm not using. But, that does not seem logical.

I updated to the latest CM12.1 and the GPS gets acquired a bit quicker, but still it takes 10 minutes of leaving Stava on the bike outside to get it going.